# Join on two tables gives duplicate results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table with data that I want to join unto another table. Problem is that the `join` can happen on two columns of the same table, where I want to get the first join to work and if this Fails i want the second join to give me a valid result.

Base table:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | Value |
| a1  |  a2 | val_1 |
| b1  |  b2 | val_2 |
| c1  |  c2 | val_3 |
```

join Table:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | Join_Value |
|     |  a2 | join_val_1 |
| b1  |     | join_val_2 |
| c1  |  c2 | join_val_3 |
```

What i tried was this:

```
select base.id1, base.id2, Value, isnull(j1.Join_value,j2.Join_value) Join_Value from base
left join Join j1 on j1.id1 = base.id1
left join Join j2 on j2.id2 = base.id2
```

The Result is this:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | Value | Join_Value |
| a1  |  a2 | val_1 | join_val_1 |
| b1  |  b2 | val_2 | join_val_2 |
| c1  |  c2 | val_3 | join_val_3 |
| c1  |  c2 | val_3 | join_val_3 |
```

What i want is this:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | Value | Join_Value |
| a1  |  a2 | val_1 | join_val_1 |
| b1  |  b2 | val_2 | join_val_2 |
| c1  |  c2 | val_3 | join_val_3 |
```

I hope i made my Problem clear.

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: And can you show what your "duplicate results" are?

Comment: please  update the question with the expected result

Comment: Edited my original post

Comment: Tag RDBMS you are using (SQL Server, MySQL, etc...)

Comment: @newbie . . . Your version is fine.  I've included a db<>fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get duplicate rows for for the `c1` and `c2` rows because they match on both of your `Join` table joins (`j1` and `j2`).

A quick fix is to add a `DISTINCT` to your query:

```sql
select DISTINCT base.id1, base.id2, Value, isnull(j1.Join_value,j2.Join_value) Join_Value 
from base
left join Join j1 on j1.id1 = base.id1
left join Join j2 on j2.id2 = base.id2
```

A better fix, depending on your DBMS is to use a window function:

```sql
select id1, id2, Value, Join_Value
FROM (
  select base.id1, base.id2, Value, isnull(j1.Join_value,j2.Join_value) Join_Value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY base.id1, base.id2 -- Group rows based on (id1, id2) combination
      ORDER BY j1.id1 -- If more than one row, give priority to row with "id1" value
    ) AS RowNum
  from base
  left join Join j1 on j1.id1 = base.id1
  left join Join j2 on j2.id2 = base.id2
) src
WHERE RowNum = 1 -- Only return one row
```

This will make sure you always one row maximum per `(id1, id2)` combination.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join the same table twice. Just specify the condition in the `ON`

```
select  b.ID1, b.ID2, b.[Value], j.Join_Value
from    [base] b
        inner join [join] j on  b.ID1   = j.ID1
                            or  (
                                       j.ID1    = '' 
                                and    b.ID2    = j.ID2
                                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select  *
from base b 
join [join] j on b.id1 = j.id1 or b.id2 = j.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your version does exactly what you want.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a648d19f8baa8628b3592d7e9fb7e5f9) is a db<>fiddle.

Second, for more control over the matching, you can use a lateral join.  This allows you to choose only one matching row -- say the one where both ids match:

```
select b.id1, b.id2, b.value, jt.join_value
from base b cross apply
     (select top (1) jt.*
      from jointable jt
      where b.id1 = jt.id1 or
            b.id2 = jt.id2
      order by (case when b.id1 = jt.id1 then 1 else 0 end) +
               (case when b.id2 = jt.id2 then 1 else 0 end) desc
     ) jt ;
```